# Convert the integral part fro list to int and keeping the strings as it is

Tags: python

I have a list `l = ['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']`. I want to convert the numbers that are int type and keep the rest as is.

Desired output:

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 'rt4', 'rt5']
```

I tried it in following way

ord(m['rt4'])

it gave me the following error
"TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found"

Comment: Just Under the question there is an [edit] button! Edit your question with additional information.

Comment: While you're editing you should also show what you've tried and precisely what the problem with it is as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

it should works:

```
l = ['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
def reformater(din):
    try:
        return int(din)
    except Exception:
        return din
s = [reformater(i) for i in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20functions#int) function to convert a string to an integer. This function will throw an exception if the input string is not a valid integer, so you can just return the unmodified input in that case using the [`try..catch` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```
l = ['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
def try_to_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s
m = [try_to_int(it) for it in l]
print(m)
```

---

`int()` might however accept more formats as valid integers than you want, so you could also validate the integer explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @millimoose. This helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
def RepresentsInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
l=['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
l=[int(l[i]) if RepresentsInt(l[i]) else l[i] for i in range(0,len(l))]
```

making function which checks for int.

***OR***

```
l=['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
l=[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in l]
```

just using isdigit() built-in function.